# Lazy loaded module route not able to find

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular7-router

I am trying to redirect the route to some path while it is empty. But in the first case, it getting the correct path but in while trying to redirect again it throwing 404.

In Breadcrumb, while clicked on Parent it's redirecting correctly, the route will be "/parent/child/child1", and while clicking on Child 1 its again working fine, but issue with the "Child" while clicking on it showing the route "/parent/child" only, but it should be "/parent/child/child1" route, Don't know what I am missing here.
I tried to give it the full path(i.e. ) but still the same issue {path: '', redirectTo: '/parent/child/child1', pathMatch: 'full'},

```
// App routing module
    export const App_Route: Routes = [
 { path: 'parent',
                data: {pageTitle: 'Parent'},
 loadChildren:'./modules/parent/parent.module#ParentModule'},
]

// Parent module routing

export const Parent_Route: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'child/child1', pathMatch: 'full' },
{
        path: '',
        component: rootWrapper,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'child',
                data: {pageTitle: 'Child Component'},
                loadChildren:'./child/child.module#ChildModule'
            },
]

// Child module routing

export Child_Route: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo: 'child1', pathMatch: 'full'},
{
        path: '',
        component: rootWrapper,
        children: [
            {   path: 'child1',
                component: Child1COmponent,
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'Child 1',
                    authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
                }]}]
```

Actual: It throwing 404 error.
Expected: it should redirect to the /parent/child/child1

Comment: can you share a working example of this issue?

Comment: I think your routes are incorrect for your use case.  As you know all your child routes are appended to your root routes and Router does a depth first , first match wins. That is why the first click(on the parent) works.

Comment: This is what happens when you click 'parent':::  parent route clicked -> 1st empty path route(In parent's module) activated -> redirect to child/child1 issued-> 2nd empty path route (in the child's route) activated(because of path match in the 1st empty path) -> child1 route(child of 2nd empty path route) activated. With this working mechanism , when you click on child , 1st empty path(in child module) activated, causes child1 redirect, but child1 is not a sibling route, so it issues 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing below given modifications in your routing code:

```
export const Parent_Route: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'child/child1', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
            path: 'child',
            component: rootWrapper,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    data: {pageTitle: 'Child Component'},
                    loadChildren:'./child/child.module#ChildModule'
                },
    ]

// Child module routing

export Child_Route: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo: 'child1', pathMatch: 'full'},
{
        path: 'child1',
        component: rootWrapper,
        children: [
            {   path: '',
                component: Child1COmponent,
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'Child 1',
                    authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
                }]}]
```

Comment: still the same issue